# UILabel in UICollectionViewCell on tvOS rendering text multiple times

Tags: ios, uilabel, tvos

[image]

This seems to be a bug in UICollectionView. Where the text is getting rendered multiple times despite being a single UILabel. Does anyone know how to fix this? Aside from filing a bug report and waiting for Apple? Or is this expected behaviour?

Comment: can you post the code for your cell configuration?  If you are improperly handling cell reuse this could be the result.

Comment: All I'm doing is setting the text property for the cell's uilabel

Comment: make label.text = nil, before setting new value

Comment: Are u programmatically adding the label on collectionview than that is where the problem is

Comment: No I'm using storyboards /reuse id. I tried setting nil first. Didn't work.

Comment: I've verified only one uilabel is on screen using the view inspector

Comment: Please post the relevant code. I wouldn't expect a bug in such a common use case, UICollectionViewCell works well for lots of tvOS developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the method *prepareForResue*

```
- (void)prepareForReuse { 
    myLabel.text = @""; 
}
```

Additionally it looks like you might be programmatically adding a label each time the cell is being setup. If that is the case move that line of code to an init method or `- (void)awakeFromNib`

Comment: Like Michal Ciuba requested, can you post the relevant code?